# Shortening JQuery cookies code

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, widget, refresh

I'm creating widgets that allow a user to change the color via JQuery

```
<img id="blue1" src="color_blue.png" /> 
<img id="red1" src="color_red.png" /> 
<img id="yellow1" src="color_yellow.png" /> 
<img id="green1" src="color_green.png" /> 
<img id="grey1" src="color_grey.png" />


$("img#blue1").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().css("background", "#3399cc");
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().css("border", "1px solid #1E6081");
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('h1').css("background", "#a9c0cc");
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().children('h1').css("border-bottom", "1px solid #1E6081");
});
```

etc.

I want the colors to be saved via cookies, so the user has the same colors when the page is refreshed or left, so I'm using the JQuery cookies plugin.

This is my code:

```
$("#w1 img#blue1").on("click", function() {
$.cookie('wcolor1', 'blue')
});

if ($.cookie('wcolor1') == 'blue')
{
$('#w1').css("background", "#3399cc");
$('#w1').css("border", "1px solid #1E6081");
$('#w1 h1').css("background", "#a9c0cc");
$('#w1 h1').css("border-bottom", "1px solid #1E6081");
}
```

I feel like there has to be a simpler way to do this, I have 6 widgets each with 5 color options, surely there's a way to compress these functions.

Thanks in advance for those who help.

Comment: Separate your data from your code, then you can write a generic function. Also, if you don't need to tell the server, consider `localStorage`.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly

```
$("#w1 img#blue1").on("click", function() {
```

can be replaced with

```
$("#blue1").on("click", function() {
```

As **id** in a **HTML** is supposed to be unique..

So you can write up a single event handle to handle all the `click` events

Something in these lines

```
$("#blue1, #red1, #yellow1, #green1, #grey1 ").on("click", function() {
     // get the color to be set
     var color = this.id.replace('1', '');
     $.cookie('wcolor1', color)
});
```

Or you can just give a common class to all the images that you want to have a click event and replace with a class selector..

The for the conditions where in you set the styles, you can store the colors in the form of data attributes on the element itself or write up the conditions based on which you set the color.

The first case will be about 5 lines of code .. 
The second case will be a if statement for each color where in you can set the color.
Or you can eliminate the conditions if you store the info in a hash.

```
var color = $.cookie('wcolor1'),
    mainBkg = 'defaultBackground',
    mainBorder = 'defaultBackground',
    childBkg = 'defaultBackground',
    childBorder = 'defaultBackground';


if (color === 'blue') {
    mainBkg = '#3399cc';
    mainBorder = '1px solid #1E6081',
    childBkg = '#a9c0cc',
    childBorder = '1px solid #1E6081';
}
else if(color === 'red') {
       // set the colors for red
}
..
..

var $w1 = $('#w1'),
    $h1 = $('h1', $w1);

$('#w1').css({
    "background", mainBkg,
    "border", "1px solid #1E6081"
});
$w1.css("background", mainBkg);
$w1.css("border", mainBorder);
$h1'.css("background", childBkg);
$h1.css("border-bottom", childBorder);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define your properties using an object, like this:

```
var theme = {
  blue: {
    'background-color': 'blue',
    'border' : '1px solid blue'
    //add all your "blue" theme options
  },
  green: {
    'background-color': 'green',
    'border' : '1px solid green'
     //add all your "green" theme options
  }
}
```

Then you could retrieve the options using the same function for all your themes:

```
var selectedTheme = $.cookie('wcolor1');  

if(theme[selectedTheme] !== "undefined"){
  $('#w1').css("background", theme[selectedTheme].background);
  $('#w1').css("border",  theme[selectedTheme].border);

}
```